# Dataproc on GKE doesn't use image when submitting the job

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

Why does Dataproc on GKE not support Docker images for jobs submission but uses raw code for python/R and jar for others. 
Shouldn't providing container image be the ideal way to submit job to GKE be it ordinary job or Dataproc job? Is this in plan or a work in progress?

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/dataproc-gke

Comment: This sounds like a feature request or design question that should be asked to Google directly. Easy answer is that dataproc and dataproc on GKE should provide a similar user experience so having one use containers and not the other would defeat the purpose.

Comment: That is correct. Main idea behind having Dataproc on GKE is to have single dashboard for all jobs, probably that's why. What I am looking for requires deeper integration and submitting jobs interface will change as you have mentioned. Will get in touch with Google folks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question comments, the main intent behind current iteration of Dataproc on GKE is to provide the same user experience as Dataproc on GCE. That's why it supports the same API which doesn't use Docker images to execute Spark jobs and there are no near-term plans to add support for this. That said, in the future Dataproc may decide to support some kind of containers as a first class way of submitting jobs (in addition to jars, etc).